# in-place sleep timer for bash (no GUI)

Tags: macos, sleep

Is there a sleep command for (OSX) bash that shows a countdown in place, i.e. does not scroll the terminal? Similar to what scp does. It has to work over an ssh tty. Thanks. if possible I'd like to use only bash scripting, but installing a visual sleep utility with brew is ok if one exists already. Thanks

(edit) I ended up writing a simple bash function.

```
function vsleep()
{
    unset A B;
    A=$1;
    B=$2;
    seq $A $B | while read X; do
        echo -n -e "\r$X ";
        sleep 1;
    done;
    echo -ne "\r          \n"
}
```

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: @bfontaine see edited question, added crude solution.

Comment: Can be done with http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php / tput.